# np.select to write lines of unique values in two columns of two different files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and still trying to learn the tools. I think pandas and numpy will be the best for this task, but maybe not the simplest:

I want to read two separate .csv files and write lines from each into a new file based on two conditions:

1. the values in column 2 (POS) do not match- write lines from each into a new file
2. the values in column 2 (POS) match in both files BUT the values in column 13 (GT) do not- write lines from each into a separate, new file

I have tried to cobble together the conditions and choices for `np.select`, but I'm terrible at the syntax required to read each file into memory then specify which column to match from which file, and finally how to write a new file as a choice...

any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read csv files using Pandas by using the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function. Their is also another function to [write csv file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)

You can use dataframe to hold the information you would put in the "new file" and then write it to csv.

But I would still advise you to look at data manipulation & comparison in Pandas, it will set you on a good track to learn how to interact with data frames. The [10 minutes to pandas guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) will do just fine to start learning.

Comment: thank you for the advice. I've been working my way through the guide; i think this real world example is a great way to adapt those principles

Answer (score 0):

Let's take each problem in turn. First read your CSV files to Pandas dataframe objects:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
```

The solutions below assume POS values are not repeated within a file.

> 1.the values in column 2 (POS) do not match- write lines from each into a new file

```
# get intersection of POS columns
values = set(df1['POS']) & set(df2['POS'])

# filter & concatenate
res = pd.concat([df1[df1['POS'].isin(values)], df2[df2['POS'].isin(values)])

# export to csv
res.to_csv('out1.csv')
```

> 2.the values in column 2 (POS) match in both files BUT the values in column 13 (GT) do not- write lines from each into a separate, new file

```
# get intersection of POS column
values = set(df1['POS']) & set(df2['POS'])

# filter & concatenate
res = pd.concat([df1[df1['POS'].isin(values)], df2[df2['POS'].isin(values)])

# drop rows where POS and GT are the same
res = res.drop_duplicates(subset=['POS', 'GT'])

# export to csv
res.to_csv('out2.csv')
```